# Solve $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\ln(1+xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am interested to find the limit of the following functions,

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\ln(1+xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2}$$

If the limit is not existing then what should be the reason of its not existance.

Comment: There is another post about the second limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476353/help-with-lim-x-y-0-0-fracx2yx4y2

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the polar transformation, we have:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))}{r}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r}=0
$$
Also:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^3\cos(\theta)^2\sin(\theta)}{r^4\cos(\theta)^4+r^2\sin(\theta)^2}=0
$$

Comment: I do not understand how you removed the ln in the last step before reaching to 0?

Comment: For $x\rightarrow0$, $ln(1+x)$ and $x$ are equivalent infinitesimal.

Answer (score 3):

Along the path $y=x^2$ shouldn't the second limit equal $\frac{1}{2}$? Since along the x-axis or the y-axis the limit equals zero, wouldn't that mean that the second limit doesn't exist?

Comment: You are quite correct. (And welcome to math.stackexchange!)