# Help with $\lim_{x, y\to(0, 0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The question asks to evaluate the limit and discuss the continuity of the function. I think I made steps in the right direction, but I'm not sure how to go from there

$$\lim_{x, y\to(0, 0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}?$$

I divided the numerator and the denominator by $x^2y$ and got $$\lim_{x, y \to(0, 0)} \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y}{x^2}}?$$

I was thinking of setting $a=\dfrac{x^2}{y}$ and $\dfrac 1a=\dfrac{y}{x^2}$. However, I'm not sure what $\lim_{x, y\to(0, 0)} a$ is. I suspect it's $0$, but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure if I even have to use the epsilon delta definition of a limit to prove that it exists before solving it.

Comment: This is the same limit as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933949/multivar-limit-frac2x2-yx4y2) up to a constant.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93886/computing-a-multivariable-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try $y = x$ and $x = \sqrt{|y|}$ and look at the limiting value in each case.

Comment: I got $0$ for one case and $1/2$ for the other so it worked :) but is there a more general way to do it?

Comment: If you want to prove the limit doesn't exist, then this approach is usually sufficient. If you suspect the limit does exist, then you need an epsilon-delta proof.